# getCartQty code location

Tags: magento2, product, quantity

in Magento in `Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Item\Processor.php`

`$candidate->getCartQty()` is fetching wrong quantity for some products.

I searched the whole codebase for "`getCartQty()`" and I couldn't find it! it is supposed to be coming from "`Magento\Catalog\Model Product::getCartQty`" but it is not there!.

Where is it?

Answer (score 0):

It's probably a magical getter for a `cart_qty` attribute.`

Check `$candidate` class (we can't guess it from your issue); find his methods, if there isn't any of them called getCartQty, then you probably have an attribute and this is a magical getter as said.

You can also go for xdebug and check where all this is going if you don't find.